# HQL - Aggregate function MAX() in Subquery

Tags: hibernate, subquery, hql, correlated-subquery, wavemaker

OK, this should be simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.  I know exactly how I would do this with SQL, but am very new to HQL.

Here's the deal.  I have a table that stores assignments - a document is assigned to a user.  At various times, the document gets reassigned to another user, but all assignments are stored in the assignments table for auditing purposes.  Make sense?  Something like this ...

```
id   documentID   userID   dateAssigned
--   ----------   ------   ------------
6    32           87       3/4/2013
7    83           87       2/3/2013
8    32           56       5/6/2013
9    12           56       1/2/2013
```

I need to display a list of documents which are currently assigned to a given user.  In the above example, user 56 has two documents assigned (documents 32 and 12) and user 87 has one (document 83) because document 32 was subsequently assigned to another user.  With me still?

What I want to do is return any records for a given user for any assigned documents (not subsequently reassigned).  So, if I query for user 56, I get records #8 and #9, and if I query for user 87, I get record #7.  That's what I want to do.

I can easily get a list of the latest assignments per document with the following:

```
SELECT a.id AS id, a.documentID AS documentID, a.userID AS userID, MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned FROM DocumentAssignments a GROUP BY documentID
```

That would return ...

```
id   documentID   userID   dateAssigned
--   ----------   ------   ------------
7    83           87       2/3/2013
8    32           56       5/6/2013
9    12           56       1/2/2013
```

But, of course, if I simply add a WHERE clause to this, I don't get what I really want.  For example, if I used:

```
SELECT a.id AS id, a.documentID AS documentID, a.userID AS userID, MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned FROM DocumentAssignments a WHERE userID=87 GROUP BY documentID
```

... this would return ...

```
id   documentID   userID   dateAssigned
--   ----------   ------   ------------
6    32           87       3/4/2013
7    83           87       2/3/2013
```

... which is no good, because record #6 is not the latest assigned record for document 32.

So, what I would like to do is something like ...

```
SELECT b.id AS id, b.documentID AS documentID, b.userID AS userID, b.dateAssigned AS dateAssigned FROM DocumentAssignments b WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id AS id, MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned FROM DocumentAssignments a GROUP BY documentID) AND b.userID=87
```

That is almost perfect except that, of course, the IN clause won't work because it contains two columns (id and MAX(dateAssigned)).

Understand the dilemna?  I've tried to figure out a way to use the aggregate MAX() function to qualify the grouping function, but have it not appear in the resulting recordset.  That would solve the problem.  There must be an elegant solution, but I'm not finding it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

-Foswick

Answer (score 0):

1) You can return all records, like in first HQL, and filter then in Java.

2) Other way, is filter the ID and the User in same subquery:

```
SELECT b.id AS id, b.documentID AS documentID,
b.userID AS userID, b.dateAssigned AS dateAssigned
FROM DocumentAssignments b
WHERE (b.id, b.userID) IN (SELECT a.id AS id, a.userID AS userID,
                           MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned
                           FROM DocumentAssignments a
                           GROUP BY documentID)
AND b.userID=87
```

View this examples:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-tuple

3) If the way 2 doesn't work, try filter your query add the condition where the user is the same of the latest document assigned, like this:

```
SELECT b.id AS id, b.documentID AS documentID,
b.userID AS userID, b.dateAssigned AS dateAssigned
FROM DocumentAssignments b
WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id AS id, MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned
             FROM DocumentAssignments a
             GROUP BY documentID)
AND b.userID=87
AND b.userID IN (SELECT a.userID AS userID, MAX(sa.dateAssigned) AS dateAssigned
             FROM DocumentAssignments a
             GROUP BY documentID)
```